# How to handle when client disconnects on NestJS

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs

I am working with **NestJS** and I need to know when a **client** has forced the **disconnection** or has **canceled** it. (either by mistake or because they wanted to).

For exaple, in Express it's as easy as:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (expressRequest, expressResponse) => {

    // Detecting close event
    expressRequest.on('close', function() {
        console.log('Client connection closed....!');
    });
    // Detecting end event
    expressRequest.on('end', function() {
        console.log('Client connection end....!');
    });

    expressResponse.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

The question is: *working with NestJS, what is the correct way to do it?*

Comment: I don't think there's is a standard way to achieve this with nestjs. Maybe using interceptors but I'm not sure. Could you please ask this on their discord https://discord.gg/nestjs

Answer (score 6):

The first thing I would try is using the [@Req() param decorator](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#request-object).  Assuming you're using Nests default Express adapter, then the request object received is the Express `req` object.

The following should work for you.  The rest of this post is just cleaning it up and making it more "Nest".

```
import { Controller, Get, Req } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request } from 'express';

@Controller()
export class AppController{
  @Get()
  test(@Req() req: Request): string {
   
    req.on('close', () => console.log('Doing something with closed connection'))

    return "Hello, world!"
  }
}
```

If you're planning to reuse this logic in a few controller methods, then I would also consider creating a custom decorator for it:

```
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Request } from 'express';

export const OnConnectionClosed = createParamDecorator(
  (data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext) =>
    new Observable((observer) => {
      const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest<Request>();

      request.on('close', () => observer.complete());
    }),
);
```

And then using it like the following:

```
@Controller()
export class AppController{

  @Get()
  test(@OnConnectionClosed() onClosed: Observable<void>): string {
    onClosed.subscribe({
      complete: () => console.log('Connection closed'),
    });

    return 'Hello, world!';
  }
}
```

And with that, you've created your own "Nest" way to listen for close events on the incoming request.

Comment: thanks, it is a good approach, but if it is not working for someone, try request.socket.on('close', (e) => { do stuff }) - this worked for me; my case when someone reloads page on FE and not waiting for request to finish.

Comment: @andriishupta thanks, request.socket.on('close',()=>{}) worked for me for all my use cases

Answer (score -1):

Nestjs has many different components that are executed at different times during the life cycle of a request.

The order in which these components are executed would be the following

[NestJs request Life cycle](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/request-lifecycle#summary)

- Incoming request
- Globally bound middleware
- Module bound middleware
- Global guards
- Controller guards
- Route guards
- Global interceptors (pre-controller)
- Controller interceptors (pre-controller)
- Route interceptors (pre-controller)
- Global pipes
- Controller pipes
- Route pipes
- Route parameter pipes
- Controller (method handler)
- Service (if exists)
- Route interceptor (post-request)
- Controller interceptor (post-request)
- Global interceptor (post-request)
- Exception filters (route, then controller, then global)
- Server response**

The answer to your question:
I think it should be detected in the following points

- Global interceptor (post-request)
- Controller interceptor (post-request)